# Is this a proper way to extract a byte from a NEON uint8x16_t vector?

Tags: c++, c, simd, arm64, armv7

I am a beginner to NEON intrinsics, and I wanted to work with `uint8x16_t` and also `uint8x16x4_t`. 
While working with it I came across a situation, where I wanted to extract a byte  from a `uint8x16_t`. Being naive to the details I accidentally began extracting bytes from it using the `[]` operator at runtime. But my compiler CLANG happily compiled the code, gave no errors or warnings and I got the desired output.

I searched through the ARM reference guides and I never seemed to find any reference on using the `[]` operator on a `uint8x16_t` vector, after all it's a 128 bit register and not an array!? (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

Therefore, to bring light to the issue, I tracked the origin of the vector `uint8x16_t` in the header file `arm_neon.h` and I found this:

```
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(16))) uint8_t uint8x16_t;
```

- How is this stored in computer memory ?
- Why am I able to use the `[]` operator on it directly, where I should
  be using:

  uint8_t fetch(uint8x16_t *r, int index)    {
                  unsigned char u[16];
                  vst1q_u8(u, *r);
                  return u[index];
                  }

  instead of:

  uint8_t fetch(uint8x16_t *r, int index){
          return (*r)[index];
          } // This is much faster in performance!

Every help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I able to use the `[]` operator on it directly

Because gcc / clang define it in terms of GNU C native vectors (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), which do have well-defined rules for operators.

ARM's docs probably don't guarantee that `[]` works, and there are probably some ARM compilers where it won't work.

---

It's stored in memory (or not, if just in a register or optimized away) the same as any other type.  The object-representation has the lowest element at the lowest address.  `uint8x16_t` objects are like `int` objects in most ways, in terms of the compiler being able to decide where to keep them, and optimize them away, etc.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! If I have an array of ```uint8x16_t``` like ```uint8x16_t x[16]``` will this be cached by CPU after storing it in RAM or is it directly stored in the CPU cores private caches?

Comment: @VivekanandV: It depends what asm your compiler makes.  IIRC, AArch64 has 32x 16-byte registers so it could potentially keep all 16 in vector registers.  (ARM32 only has 16 `q` registers).  If your compiler does end up storing / reloading some or all of them to memory, it's no different from other stores and reloads.  It will eventually write back to RAM if / when those cache lines get evicted from write-back L1d cache, assuming your CPU core does have such a cache.  But later reads can hit in cache.

Comment: I was trying to protect a lookup table from cache timing attacks, by storing its data in a four element array of  ```uint8x16x4_t``` which is equivalent to 16 ```q``` registers. The lookup table contains 256 bytes, which will be loaded to these registers. My assumption, is that, the data being inside CPU registers, the attacker will have great difficulty in reaching conclusions about my access patterns. Am I correct, or is there a bigger picture, that I dont understand ?